# Make list with all employeenames + details

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, user-profile, user-profile-property

I would like to make a list with all employees and their current project.
The idea is that employees enter their current project(s) in their profile.
Then on our site I would like to have a list with employeenames + actual projects.
Ideally this list is grouped per project.

I added a custom field (CurrentProject)  to the userprofile but I cannot seem to get these two simple fields (name + CurrentProject) in a list on a page.

What would be the simplest way to do this?
How to minimize the effort asked of my colleagues?

Thanks for thinking with me.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you do it someone is going to have to do the work of selecting and managing what employees are working on any given project. With that said how many employees will be using this and how many projects are in the que? My thoughts were to simply build a project list of some sort where you can have a simple people picker column to allow users to add their name as it relates to them working on that project. Keep the list simple only with the most important columns you need for tracking purposes and I think you should be fine.

Comment: At the moment it is 50 consultants but growing fast. I added a field to everybody's profile and most are busy now filling that field. The only thing I need now is a list of people with their accompanying project.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use the User Profile. Properly configured there is already an entry for every employee. You can use one of the OOB fields or create your own. If you want to curate the list then use Managed Metadata and bind the User Profile Property to the MMS Term Set.

You can then make that field a Refinable Managed Property and add it to the People Search Results page to help folks search for Project Team members. You can add a People Search Web part to the home page of the Project Site and set the query to return results for that project only and now you have a self maintain list of team members.

Comment: "add it to the People Search Results page to help folks search for Project Team members"  <-- How would I do that?

Comment: Add a Refinable Managed Property to Search and then following a full crawl of your user profiles you can add the property as a refiner to the People Search Page. I cover this in my search solutions series: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2017/07/24/search-based-site-directory-part-4/